# Writing handlers for JS.Window.Onpopstate in Websharper

Tags: f#, browser-history, websharper

I'm trying to get proper back-button support in my WebSharper-app. I can put stuff in history just fine:

```
type MyRecord = { foo: int; bar: string } 
JS.Window.History.PushState({foo=10; bar="hello"}, "", "mysuffix")
```

I was hoping to add a corresponding handler for `onpopstate` by doing something like this:

```
JS.Window.Onpopstate <- (fun e -> Javascript.Console.Info e.State.bar)
```

Unfortunately, this event has type `Js.Window.Onpopstate : Dom.Event -> Unit`
and `Dom.Event` doesn't have a field `State` for getting back the state, even though the corresponding "real" Javascript event does.

How do I access state stored with `PushState` in the `Onpopstate` handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access arbitrary fields from objects using the dynamic operator `?`:

```
JS.Window.Onpopstate <- (fun e ->
    Console.Info e?state.bar
)
```

Note however that you still need to use `[<Inline>]` to call an arbitrary method.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can retrieve values from arbitrary Javascript like this:

```
[<Inline "$e.state">]
let stateOf (e : JavaScript.Dom.Event) = 
   Unchecked.defaultof<MyRecord>
```

I can now write my `onpopstate` handler:

```
JS.Window.Onpopstate <- (fun e -> 
  Javascript.Console.Info ((stateOf e).bar)
)
```

A caveat is that supplying nested records, class-type arguments, and Sets to `PushState` in general doesn't work. The browser is obligated to store only the JSON-serializable part of whatever you pass to `PushState`; and all the types just mentioned are implemented as Javascript objects.